# How to fix 'File or assembly "System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime" not found'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, windows-runtime, monogame

After a reinstallation of Windows 10 I get the error

> The file or assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime,
>   Version=4.0.11.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or
>   a dependency not found

I am making a Game in Monogame c#. I tried the solution others recommended like setting the versions of the same packages equal. I searched for "WindowsRuntime" and "4.0.11.0" but I couldn't find anything

The error happens here so here is the code in this constructor:

```
public Game1()
{
  graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this)
  {
    PreferredBackBufferWidth = settings.resolutionWidth,
    PreferredBackBufferHeight = settings.resolutionHeight,
    IsFullScreen = settings.IsFullscreen
  };
  IsMouseVisible = settings.IsMouseVisible;
  Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
}
```

[image: Picture of the Error]

Here  is the *app.config*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0"
sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1"/></startup></configuration>
```

And here the *packages.config*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="TexturePacker-MonoGameLoader" version="1.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I installed the same Monogame version as before (I had the installer file in my project folder just for sure) and Visual Studio 2017 Professional with the same settings.

The project shouldn't have changed as well as I had it backed up on an external drive.

***Edit:***
This happens when having the project on any other drive than C:

Comment: check if the `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime`is included in your references. Maybe there is a yellow triangle that the filepath is not found

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer I checked it but there is no `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime´, when I try to add it I can't find it either.

Comment: which .NetFramework are you running? You have to search for `System.Runtime` at the references, without the `WindowsRuntime`

Comment: I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.1.
This are the `System.Runtime.` that I have:
Caching, DurableInstancing, InteropService.RuntimeInformation, Remoting, Serialization, Serialization.Formatters.Soap.
And `System.Workflow.Runtime`

Comment: check the versions at `app.config` and `packages.config`. Your exception is showing two different versions.

Comment: I added them to the initial question as I'm not sure what the versions are you mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187763/discussion-between-mario-mitterbauer-and-mrminemeet).